# How to define rule in controller in yii 1.10

Tags: php, yii

I have one table, which i have divided in two section for each i have mention two action under controller, i wanted to separate validation rule for both action, so i don't want use common model rule.

Is there any way by which i can write rule in action.

I have user controller there i have defined two action called `frontuser` and `backenduser`. 
my action in controller

```
public function actionfrontuserCreate()
{
     // want to write rule here
}

public function actionbackenduserCreate()
{
     // want to write rule here
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i hope i can help you:

rules should be declared in the model even if the model is shared between one or more controllers with different kind of actions ...

but you do not want a rule to be executed in all of those actions so you specify wich actions can take that rule using [scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh3), i leave you an example:

```
array('password_repeat', 'required', 'on'=>'register'),
```

code above only makes pasword_repeat required on scenario register

then in your controller you will specify wich scenario will be used...

```
$modelA = User::model()->findByPk(1); // $model->scenario = 'update'
$modelB = new User();                 // $model->scenario = 'insert'
$modelB->scenario = 'light';          // custom scenario
if ($modelB->validate()) {  ...
```

i hope this solve your issue, for bonus i suggest to check default yii scenarios    insert, update, delete ....

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules go in the model not in the controller. What you want to do is use scenarios.
When you put a rules in the model you can do something like:

```
array('username', 'required', 'on'=>'frontUserCreate'),
```

By using the 'on'=>'...' part you can tell in what scenario the rule must be applied.
In your controller when you create a new model you should give the scenario as a parameter:

```
public function actionfrontuserCreate()
{
    $model = new User('frontUserCreate');
    if (isset($_POST['User']) {
        ....
    }
    $this->render('viewname', array('model'=>$model));
}
```